# Limit a number of SQL queries with aggregated entities

Tags: php, performance, optimization, doctrine

Let's say I have `users` and `things` tables. Each user can have many things. One thing is assigned to exactly one user.

I have a code to fetch all things:

```
$things = $this->createQueryBuilder('t')->getQuery()->getResult();
```

To display all users details I do this:

```
foreach ($things as $thing) {
    var_dump($thing->getUser()->getName());
}
```

The problem is this code needs n+1 queries (1 query to fetch all n things and n queries to fetch all users assigned to them).

The question is: does it possible to somehow build all things objects with assigned users objects using one query?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it possible by joining and adding to select the related table User

```php
$things = $this->createQueryBuilder('t')
            ->addSelect('u')
            ->join('t.user', 'u')
            ->getQuery()->getResult();
```

`user` in `t.user` is the name of your property in the Thing class.